# Viewport Units for font size

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have tried using viewport units for font-size and have found that the sizes did not scale uniformly as I wanted them to.

On the same browser (chrome) across different operating systems the browser with a smaller screen size running OS X had larger, more legible font than the windows one with the one with the bigger screen / resolution.

On same browser, on the same os (windows) but different device (same aspect ratio), the fonts look totally different.

I have read earlier about different operating systems rendering font differently but that is not the case in the 2nd senerio. Is the implementation of viewport units for font-sizes still buggy? Rendering with `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` is also not helping much. Should I just stick to px / em for now or is there some css property that I missed that can help minimise these effects.

Comment: All the latest browsers support `vw`, so that's not the problem. Are you sure it's not the particular font size of the particular font it's displayed at? I know of various occasions where a font looks nice at nearly all sizes, except for, say, 17px, in one browser.

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS - are you sure you're not on a retina screen with a higher resolution?

In any case, in regards to font-size, I believe px or em should be a better choice. I usually use px for majority of code, simply because that way you have full control and don't need to worry about browsers calculating em actual size differently due to parents' inheritance (IE - I am looking at you!). In general, I don't, personally, believe there are a lot of valid use cases for using viewport units as font size and that you can achieve more consistent results by using px or ems along with media queries.

Comment: The IE problem with inherited ems was long, long ago. If you still have that, are you sure you're not running your sites in quirks mode? Otherwise, good point with the retina screen.

Comment: @MrLister, just last year I wasted hours and hours of time trying to find out why some icons (font icons) were differently sized than others - despite being defined as same sizes and some of the sibling icons were completely ok. Doing some digging, I finally changed the value from em to px and the problem was gone. The problem was in IE11 in Edge compatibility mode. So, in some cases, it can still happen and when it does, it takes a long long time before you find out what's the problem :)

Comment: so building a site with res > 8k in mind is not plausible at the moment? :)

Comment: @feetnappy That's why we use CSS pixels instead of hardware dots ;) Now if we could only get the software to collaborate...

Comment: @feetnappy - I wouldn't optimize it for 8k just yet, personally, no. I mean, the market share and amount of users don't outweigh the extra cost for that to be optimized and perfect at the moment.